# Regex restringir cantidad de dominios de orden superior

Tags: regex, lenguaje-agnóstico

Estoy empezando con regex y quería extraer de este texto:

```
Carlos Arturo   
449 123 45 67
carlos_@hotmail.com
www.carlos.com

Manuel Alejandro
448-234-56-78
alejandro@outlook.com
https://www.manuel.alejandro.com.mx
http://alejandro.com.mx

Cesar Alan
449 345 67 89
cesar@hotmail.com
cesar.net
```

todas las url's que no sean mails, por ejemplo `'www.carlos.com', 'https://www.manuel.alejandro.com.mx', 'http://alejandro.com.mx', 'cesar.net'` serian válidos, me funciona bien con la siguiente formula:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?(www)?\.?[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/gm
```

Ahora quiero agregar una condición más, la cantidad de nombres de dominio superior tienen que ser de 2 como máximo, por ejemplo 'nombredepagina.com.ar', 'nombredepagina.com' serian válidos y url's como 'nombredepagina.com.org.es' no serían validas. Ya intente de varias formas pero puedo estar creando url's con 15 dominios se orden superior separados por puntos e igual me las acepta, hay algo en la fórmula que no está bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más cerca que he podido lograr es validar dominios de nivel superior de 2 caracteres o más (no olvides los nuevos TLD), y me quedan afuera algunos que consideras "válidos". No sé si con regex únicamente se pueda lograr un control tan fino como propones, ya que para una expresión

manuel.alejandro.com.mx

nombredepagina.com.org.es

son equivalentes, cuatro frases separadas de puntos. Sino tendríamos que ponernos a analizar todos los gTLD válidos, y ya con regex, no imposible, pero engorroso.

#### Expresión regular

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www)?\.?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.){1,2}[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

#### Ejemplos

[www.carlos.com](http://www.carlos.com) ✅

https://www.manuel.alejandro.com.mx ❌

https://manuel.alejandro.com.mx ❌

http://alejandro.com.mx ✅

cesar.net ✅

nombredepagina.com ✅

nombredepagina.com.ar ✅

nombredepagina.com.org.es ❌

## Enlace de regexr

https://regexr.com/771pf